# Xcode: iOS linker error when linking external frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm just starting iOS development.

I am trying to add frameworks to my app, but then get a linker error:

> ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/user/Google
>   Drive/spring 2015/romo
>   project/RomoSDK_v1.0C/frameworks/RMCore.framework/RMCore, **missing
>   required architecture x86_64 in file** /Users/user/Google Drive/spring
>   2015/romo project/RomoSDK_v1.0C/frameworks/RMCore.framework/RMCore (3
>   slices)ignoring file /Users/user/Google Drive/spring 2015/romo
>   project/RomoSDK_v1.0C/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion, missing
>   required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/user/Google Drive/spring
>   2015/romo project/RomoSDK_v1.0C/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion (3
>   slices)

Any ideas why I would get this error and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you have set the project to build for the iOS simulator,which is running on the x86_64 architecture. And the error tells you that this architecture is not supported by the romo framework.
Check what happens when you change to compile for a real device, the error should be gone.
I don't know the romo framework, but my guess would be that it only provides the armv6, armv7 and arm64 architectures for real iOS devices.